# Using Delegated Permissions from Daemon that uses Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Daemon that accesses some users' emails in order to forward them automatically. I registered the Daemon in Azure and requested a number of Application Permissions, which were granted by an Admin.
I was then able to obtain a oAuth2 token and the application runs just as expected.

Now my IT department is asking me if, instead of having full rights on every mailbox, the app can impersonate a single user so that only that User's emails can be read and forwarded by the Daemon.

So I registered another app on Azure and only requested Delegated Permissions for it (I selected all Delegated Permissions that do NOT require approval by an admin, 44 in all).
I then built my authorization URL and sent that to the user in question. The user clicked on the link, was presented with a list of all the permissions the app had requested, and consented to granting those permissions to the app.

My app then received an authorization code, as expected. The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-authorization-code-to-request-an-access-token) then states I can use that code to obtain a token for accessing the user's mailbox. So I built the REST parameters using the instructions provided by MS:

```
"grant_type=authorization_code" +
"&client_id={appID}+ 
"&client_secret={appSecret} + 
"&code={auth_code}+
"&redirect_uri={Same_Redirect_URI_used_when_obtaining_Authorization_Code} +
"&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"
```

And I issue a POST request with this content to the authorization URL, as specified in the documentation:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantID}/oauth2/token
```

Now the strange thing about this is that as soon as my script runs the `xhr.send(tmpSnd);` method (where *tmpSnd* contains the above REST parameters), I immediately get a `msxml3.dll: Access is denied error`. I would, at the very least, have expected that error to come back as part of the response from the POST, but I never even get past the **send()** method.

Here's the JS code I use to obtain a Token:

```
  this.getDelegatedToken = function(appEndPoint, appID, appSecret,auth_Code,appURI){
    var result=null;
    var GRAPH_URL_TOKEN = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + appEndPoint + "/oauth2/token";
    xhr.open("POST", GRAPH_URL_TOKEN, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var params ="grant_type=authorization_code" +
        "&client_id="     + appID + 
        "&client_secret=" + appSecret + 
        "&code="          + auth_Code+
        "&redirect_uri="  +appURI +
        "&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com";

    xhr.send(params);
    if(xhr.status==200) {
      result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
    return result;
  };
```

I think I read somewhere that using only Delegated Permissions can cause an issue with Daemons, but for the life of me I can't recall where I read it (using Graph requires a LOT of reading!).

**EDIT**

If I set the *&code* parameter to an invalid value, I do receive the expected  error message (*"Code is malformed or invalid"*). If I set it to a previous authorization code that has since expired, I also get the expected error message (*"The provided authorization code or refresh code is expired"*). So it would seem all my POST parameters are valid, since I receive the proper error messages when I purposely pass an invalid one. I just don't understand why, when I pass all the correct parameters, I don't even get an error response back, I only get an *Access is denied* message from the XHR object.

Can anyone spot any glaring mistake in the code or the process?

Comment: Are you running that from front-end JavaScript?

Comment: I am running this from an in-app instance of the Windows Scripting Host. There is no web browser involved. The application itself runs as a Windows service, which means no GUI is involved. In a way, it's similar to what NodeJS would do. Except it's not NodeJS, it's a Windows executable (written in Delphi) that instanciates WSH.
Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Just want to confirm that your tenantID (the variable called appEndPoint) looks like "contoso.com" (for your organization, of course).

Comment: I've tried it with both the DNS (myprefix.myorg.com) and the application ID displayed on the Azure Portal.

Comment: I hope you are not mixing up v2 APIs and v1 APIs. Tokens and Codes can't be shared between v2 and v1 APIs

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the authorization code, you need to make a POST to the Token Endpoint. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

> Now that you've acquired an authorization code and have been granted
> permission by the user, you can redeem the code for an access token to
> the desired resource, by sending a POST request to the `/token`
> endpoint:
>
> // Line breaks for legibility only
>
> ```
> POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> grant_type=authorization_code
> &client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e
> &code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrqqf_ZT_p5uEAEJJ_nZ3UmphWygRNy2C3jJ239gV_DBnZ2syeg95Ki-374WHUP-i3yIhv5i-7KU2CEoPXwURQp6IVYMw-DjAOzn7C3JCu5wpngXmbZKtJdWmiBzHpcO2aICJPu1KvJrDLDP20chJBXzVYJtkfjviLNNW7l7Y3ydcHDsBRKZc3GuMQanmcghXPyoDg41g8XbwPudVh7uCmUponBQpIhbuffFP_tbV8SNzsPoFz9CLpBCZagJVXeqWoYMPe2dSsPiLO9Alf_YIe5zpi-zY4C3aLw5g9at35eZTfNd0gBRpR5ojkMIcZZ6IgAA
> &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
> &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
> &client_secret=p@ssw0rd
>
> //NOTE: client_secret only required for web apps
> ```

It does not seem like you are doing this correctly in your code above. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I made mistakes when copy/pasting my code... I have now corrected them in my original post. As you can see, I'm using the exact same values as specified in the MS Documentation, yet I still get the same "Access is denied" error when calling the xhr.send() method (by the way, xhr is an instance of  Microsoft.XMLHTTP)

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming, when you use client secret ,you get app only token.This token has no access for resource. To use App only token to access resources,you need app permission (instead of delegated ) on azure portal.Add Applications Permission check and see if you still get the access denied error

Comment: As I explained in my initial post, I _know_ using Application Permissions works, but my IT department wants me to use Delegated Permissions and that's where I'm running into trouble.

Comment: You need Daemon to run on users account (delegate) .Isn't this a contradiction.Services do not run on per user account.Even if you make any web hook (where you can use delegate) and call from your daemon ,I cannot think of a way to get user context without involving a user.

Comment: The Daemon must be able to access _only_ the accounts for which users have given their permission. If the Daemon uses Application Permissions, then it has access to all accounts, which is what my IT department doesn't like. The Daemon has a list of accounts to monitor, and for each of these accounts it must be able to retrieve and then forward messages.